# Functional tests: calls to MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, functional-testing, android-testing

Using the Android testing framework, I want to write functional (end-to-end) tests for an application that uses `MediaPlayer`. The application is a simple GUI that lets the user play tracks. I want to write tests that simulate touch events on (for example) the play button. The automated functional tests will then check that when the play button is pressed, the media player plays the selected track.

How can I test if `MediaPlayer` is playing a given track, from within the test case? (Assuming this is a good implementation of an end-to-end test for an application that plays music).

I'm using [this example code](http://developer.android.com/training/activity-testing/activity-functional-testing.html) as a starting point.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to choose Espresso as core library for functional testing.

A sketch for end-to-end test could look like this:

```
public class PlaybackManagerTest {

    public void testShouldStartPlayingSelectedTrack() {
        onView(withId(R.id.track_play)).perform(click());

        assertTrue(playbackManager.isPlaying());
        assertEquals("desired_track.mp3", playbackManager.getCurrentTrackPath();
    }
}
```

`PlaybackManager` might represent API; wrap a `MediaPlayer` instance, keep track of playback history, etc.

Comment: How to retrieve playbackManager? Should be an important point which lacks in your answer